# Add a custom action button in WooCommerce admin order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I have followed [this instructions](https://fernandoacosta.net/blog/2015/06/07/woocommerce-adicionar-novo-status-de-pedido/) to add a custom order status for my WooCommerce Orders.

I can't find a way to create a custom  action button that changes the order status to my custom status from the admin order list page like this screenshot:

[image: This image shows where I want it to be.]

I would like this custom action button to be shown for the orders that have a "Processing" status.

I could not find any answer in WooCommerce documentation.

Is there a hook to apply these buttons? 
How can I add it in the `function.php`?

Thank you

Comment: Here by pressing the button we save a new status, but and is it possible to save or update a meta? with "update_post_meta"? According to an input on the line? I tried with a link but a button would also go :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59939550/wordpress-add-a-button-to-save-an-order-directly-in-the-order-list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To resume, you have created a custom order status 'wc-parcial' (with the instructions code provided in your question) and you need to add a related action button to orders admin list.

> For WooCommerce version 3.3+ check the update [in **this answer** below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961145/3730754)

You need to use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_admin_order_actions`** filter hook

```
// Add your custom order status action button (for orders with "processing" status)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button( $actions, $order ) {
    // Display the button for all orders that have a 'processing' status
    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'processing' ) ) ) {

        // Get Order ID (compatibility all WC versions)
        $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
        // Set the action button
        $actions['parcial'] = array(
            'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=parcial&order_id=' . $order_id ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
            'name'      => __( 'Envio parcial', 'woocommerce' ),
            'action'    => "view parcial", // keep "view" class for a clean button CSS
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Set Here the WooCommerce icon for your action button
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css() {
    echo '<style>.view.parcial::after { font-family: woocommerce; content: "\e005" !important; }</style>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works. You will get that:

[image]

Comment: can we use this to add a private order note in specific order from the all orders page ?

Comment: @FaizAli You can use action buttons for almost everything related to orders. Now, I don't really catch your question, sorry.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I want to use the action button to add a private note to an order while staying on that All Orders (orders archive) page. maybe with ajax

Comment: @FaizAli Yes JavaScript with Ajax seems to be mandatory for that.

Answer (score 4):

> Updated version for Woocommerce 3.3+

To resume, *you have created a custom order status 'wc-parcial' (with the instructions code provided in your question) and you need to add a related action button to orders admin list.*

The new code:

```
// Add your custom order status action button (for orders with "processing" status)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button( $actions, $order ) {
    // Display the button for all orders that have a 'processing' status
    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'processing' ) ) ) {

        // The key slug defined for your action button
        $action_slug = 'parcial';

        // Set the action button
        $actions[$action_slug] = array(
            'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=parcial&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
            'name'      => __( 'Envio parcial', 'woocommerce' ),
            'action'    => $action_slug,
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Set Here the WooCommerce icon for your action button
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css() {
    $action_slug = "parcial"; // The key slug defined for your action button

    echo '<style>.wc-action-button-'.$action_slug.'::after { font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e029" !important; }</style>';
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works

[image]

Comment: If you think it isn't working you must click on "adjust view" in the upper right corner and check the "actions" to see it in the table view