# Add img to custom action buttons in admin order list for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, orders

Is there any way to get the img src in Woocommerce admin order list:
That is the code of my PDF button, I just want to get the src image, I have two buttons 'Invoice' and 'Packing Slip', I want every button to get an image

```
// Add custom action buttons in woocommerce order list
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_print_actions_buttons', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_print_actions_buttons( $actions, $order ) {
    $opts = get_option('xc_woo_cloud_print_options', array());

    //if (isset($opts['printer']) && $opts['printer'] != "") {
        $domain = 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips';

        $slugs_label_names = array(
            'invoice'       => __('Invoice', $domain ),
            'packing-slip'  => __('Packing Slip', $domain )
        );

        // Set the action button
        foreach ( $slugs_label_names as $slug => $label_name ) {
            $actions[$slug] = array(
                'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "admin-ajax.php?action=xc_woo_printer_job&document_type={$slug}&order_id=" . $order->get_id()), 'xc_woo_printer_job'),
                'alt' => esc_attr("Print " . $label_name),
                'title' => "Print " . $label_name
                'img' =>

            );
        }
    //}
 $actions = apply_filters('xc_woo_printer_meta_box_actions', $actions, $post_id);

    foreach ($actions as $document_type => $data) {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" class="button tips xc_ajax_button <?php echo $document_type; ?>" target="_blank" alt="<?php echo $data['alt']; ?>" data-tip="<?php echo $data['alt']; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $data['alt']; ?>" width="16">
            </a>
            <?php
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (based on your question code)

```
// Add your custom action buttons
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_print_actions_buttons', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_print_actions_buttons( $actions, $order ) {
    $opts = get_option('xc_woo_cloud_print_options', array());

    if (isset($opts['printer']) && $opts['printer'] != "") {
        $domain = 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips';

        $slugs_label_names = array(
            'invoice'       => __('Invoice', $domain ),
            'packing-slip'  => __('Packing Slip', $domain )
        );

        // Set the action button
        foreach ( $slugs_label_names as $slug => $label_name ) {
            $actions[$slug] = array(
                'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( "admin-ajax.php?action=xc_woo_printer_job&document_type={$slug}&order_id=" . $order->get_id()), 'xc_woo_printer_job'),
                'name'      => $label_name,
                'action'    => $slug,
            );
        }
    }

    return $actions;
}

// Set Here the WooCommerce icon for your action button
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_print_actions_buttons_css' );
function add_custom_print_actions_buttons_css() {
    $slug_icons = array(
        'invoice'       => '\f497', // '\e02b',
        'packing-slip'  => '\f491', // '\e028',
    );
    // Added Woocommerce compatibility version
    $class  = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.3', '<' ) ? '.view.' : '.wc-action-button-';

    echo '<style>';

    foreach ( $slug_icons as $slug => $icon_code )
        echo $class.$slug.'::after { font-family: dashicons !important; content: "'.$icon_code.'" !important; font-size:1.4em !important; margin-top: -4px !important; }';

    echo '</style>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works, it should work for you too.

[image]

---

**Woocommerce and Wordpress available icons**: *(visual + icon code)*:

- Available WC Icons: https://rawgit.com/woothemes/woocommerce-icons/master/demo.html
- Available WP Icons: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#chart-bar

---

Similar related answers:

- [Add a custom action button in WooCommerce admin order list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516819/add-a-custom-action-button-in-woocommerce-admin-order-list/48961145#48961145)
- [Backend orders list custom action buttons in Woocommerce 3.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959047/backend-orders-list-custom-action-buttons-in-woocommerce-3-3/48960294#48960294)

Comment: Hello, your code work well, but without icons, is there any possibility to add an image instead of icons, and also I wanted to add another class called 'xc_ajax_button'

Comment: As you can see in screenshot, there is font icons on the buttons that are set in the last function… I have addes the 2 links for Woocommerce and Wordpress available icons (visual + icon code). I have added other related answers links. **Now, for your other class called 'xc_ajax_button'** you'll have to try to adapt it in the functions code, as I can't test anything related (or ask a new question, giving more explanations, details and all related code).

Comment: I added the class 'xc_ajax_button' and I changed some stuff in the code all I wanted is to get the img url, I will ask a new question or I will edit that page

Comment: @Simo There is no images url for woocommerce actions buttons in backend order list… it has to be an icon font… So you should better ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the icon, in your code you wrote a wrong class (wc-action-button-),  I don't have this class in my button, I changed the class name and I added another point and then everything is working well, anyway thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Simo this was for Woocommerce version 3.3 (as in my screenshot) which has a different class… So I have updated my code adding Woocommerce compatibility versions.